# How to remove duplicates in spatial database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sqlgeography, ssms-2012

I don't have much experience in work with Spatial Database and want to ask, how can I check for doublets in spatial DB ?
Is it possible to do it with SQL? How to check polygons geometry?

Comment: Which dbms, SQL Server? Also... _[doublets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublet_(clothing))_?

Comment: It is actually on SQL Server 2008 and an copy on Microsoft Server SQL 2012 Studio.

Comment: Check out [`SqlGeography.STEquals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stequals.aspx)